# Not able to get the values in JSON from Variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, json, variable-substitution

I have written small Shell/bash script, where I have some data in `sampleData.txt` file which I want to convert in Base64 and to pass it in variable `$scriptPayload`:

```
value=$(cat sampleData.txt)
echo "$value"
encoded= echo  $value | base64 
scriptPayload='{"scriptText":"$encoded" }'
echo "$scriptPayload"
```

but the output which Ii am geting is literally `{"scriptText":"$encoded"}`.
I t should take value from `$encoded` variable like `{"scriptText":"Test the Shell Script and its behaviour" }`

Please suggest. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has a syntax error (not actualy, but it's definitely not doing what you think it does):

```bsh
encoded= echo  $value | base64
```

This could, assuming you're using a shell such as `bash`, be written as

```bsh
encoded=$( base64 <<<"$value" )
```

or even

```bsh
encoded=$( base64 <sampleData.txt )
```

which captures the base64-encoding of the data in the file `sampleData.txt` into the variable `encoded` using a command substitution, in a similar way to how you're already using `cat` in a command substitution on your first line of code.

Since variables are not expanded within single-quoted strings, the code

```bsh
scriptPayload='{"scriptText":"$encoded" }'
```

will not do what you think it does (it sets `scriptPayload` to the literal string `{"scriptText":"$encoded" }`).

In `bash`, this is better written as

```bsh
printf -v scriptPayload '{"scriptText":"%s"}' "$encoded"
```

or

```bsh
printf -v scriptPayload '{"scriptText":"%s"}' "$( base64 <sampleData.txt )"
```

The `printf` utility built into `bash` prints directly into a variable with `-v varname`.

Note that some `base64` utility implementations may produce data with CRLF line-endings though.

---

Using `jo`:

```
scriptPayload=$( jo scriptText=%sampleData.txt )
printf '%s\n' "$scriptPayload"
```

The argument `scriptText=%sampleData.txt` tells `jo` to create a JSON object with a key `scriptText`.  The data for that key should be the base64-encoded contents of the file `sampleData.txt` (it's the `%` that decides that it should be base64-encoded).

With a file, `sampleData.txt`, containing the string `Hello World` (followed by a newline), this would output

```
{"scriptText":"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQK"}
```

`jo` is a tool for effortlessly creating properly encoded and quoted JSON data on the command line or in shell scripts.

Comment: `<<<` in bash (like in zsh but contrary to Byron Rakitzis's clone of `rc`, the two shells where the feature originate from) adds a newline character (and `value=$(cat sampleData.txt)` strips trailing newline character**s** if any). You'd need `printf %s "$value" | base64`

Answer (score 0):

```
encoded=`base64 -w0 < sampleData.txt`
scriptPayload='{"scriptText":"'"$encoded"'" }'
echo "$scriptPayload"
```

Try above piece of code. The reason your variable was not evaluating is because you encapsulated it inside single quotes. I happen to close single quote just before variable. That way shell would recognise a variable and replace it with actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your line for encoding was not doing anything, I changed it. Plus I also changed the line for the final `scriptPayload` and used escaping.

```
#!/bin/bash
value=5
echo $value
encoded=`echo -n "$value" | base64`
scriptPayload="{\"scriptText\":\"${encoded}\" }"
echo $scriptPayload
```